# access array element in elasticsearch using elastic4s

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, elastic4s

I wanted to delete an element from the Array, as shown below I inserted a testindiex with type test and document with an Array inside, in elasticsearch using elastic4s.

I wanted to delete a value ex: tony from members - how can I do this

```
   val insert = client.execute {
  indexInto("testindex"/"test") id 1 fields(
      "members" -> Array(
      "tony",
      "salvidor",
      "bobby"
    ),
    "crews" -> Seq(
      "gualtieri",
      "baccalieri",
      "barese",
      "moltisanti"
    )
  )
}.await
```

Here what i did:

```
 val deleted=client.execute {
    deleteIn("testindex"/"test").by(termQuery("crews","gualtieri"))
  }.await
```

but this deletes entire document instead of single record, help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Element delete/update from a nested/Array JSON from Elasticsearch

Input: JSON Document

```
{
  "members" -> Array(
    "tony",
    "salvidor",
    "bobby"
  ),
  "crews" ->
    "gualtieri"

)
```

Below commands for adding  and removing the elements  from an Array

add Command:  Adding elements to an Array in a JSON document

```
 val resp = client.execute { updateIn(indexname,doctype).query("crews", "gualtieri")  script {
  script("ctx._source.members.add(params.key)").params(Map("key"->"space"))
} }.await
```

remove Command: Removing  elements from an Array in a JSON document

```
val resp1 = client.execute { updateIn(indexname,doctype).query("crews", "gualtieri")  script {
  script("ctx._source.members.remove(ctx._source.members.indexOf('salvidor'))")
    //.params(Map("key"->"abc"))
} }.await
```

removeAll Command: Removing the all same elements from an Array.

```
val resp2 = client.execute { updateIn("testindex","test").query("crews", "gualtieri")  script {
  script("ctx._source.members.removeAll(Collections.singleton('space'))")
} }.await
```

Comment: How to create template using elastic4s from json haveing setting and mapping details.